# Consejo inicio proyecto Big Data

Tags: python, json, mongodb, curl, nosql

Buenas noches,

Me han asignado un proyecto y no se realmente por donde empezar. Mediante curl recibo un json, el cliente quiere guardar cada segundo los datos recibidos.

Ahora mismo tienen una tarea cron que llama a un archivo php que realiza un insert en una BBDD MySQL de cada parametro recibido en el json. Este cron se ejecuta cada minuto e internamente el archivo php se realiza la conexión a la BBDD, y mediante un bucle se genera cada segundo el insert, por lo que el archivo ejecuta en un bucle 60 inserts. Sin contar los 200mil registros que pueden haber diarios.

Esto no lo veo demasiado optimo por lo que he propuesto migrar a mongodb. ¿Lo veis bien?

La otra duda es sobre el motor de este sistema, había pensado en un python que recoja el json directamente y lo registre sin más en el archivo mongo. Pero como se podría hacer esto de la forma más óptima posible? Seguiriais usando un cron?

No necesito el código, es más un consejo de como iniciarlo, por donde encaminariais el proyecto, si hay algo que no estoy teniendo en cuenta, etc...

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola.. asi como esta tu pregunta es una consulta que no tiene una respuesta correcta, y no se alinea al formato de SO.. trata de mejorarla segun la guia de la [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Me parece que dada la naturaleza de los datos y la temporalidad con la que se reciben Mongo sería lo mejor y podrías prescindir del cron, porque con el tiempo perderás datos, mejor implementalo con un ciclo que verifique que se cumpla cada segundo y tenga un tiempo de espera, así la perdida de tiempo será solo de milesimas y no habrá datos extraviados (esto ocurre con cron por los hilos de procesamiento en el procesador)